# Regex pattern to stop only accept what's left on that line

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

My following data:

`'DOMA A\r\nName: Ryan\r\nBest: 1\r\nAlias: 3K\r\nLocation: Eng\r\nGame Wins: 51\r\nTime: 09:10:50'`

Has some problems when using regex patterns to find everything...

```
pattern1 = re.compile('DOMA: (.*)\r\n')
pattern2 = re.compile('Name: (.*)\r\n')
pattern3 = re.compile('Best: (.*)\r\n')
pattern4 = re.compile('Location: (.*)\r\n')
pattern5 = re.compile('Game Wins: (.*)\r\n')
pattern6 = re.compile('Time: (.*)')
```

All of the above work however sometimes my data looks like: 
`'DOMA A\r\nName: Ryan\r\nBest: 1\r\nAlias: 3K\r\nLocation: Eng\r\nGame Wins: 51\r\nTime: 09:10:50\r\nREF: Yes'`

Pattern6, returns incorrectly because it doesn't have /r/n... how can I get around this so that it only returns what's on it's current line...~

Is pattern 6 supposed to be like:

```
pattern6 = re.compile(r'Time: (.*)')
```

or

```
pattern6 = re.compile('Time: (.*?)')
```

or

```
pattern6 = re.compile(r'Time: (.*?)')
```

Thanks in advance
- Hyflex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This the the sort of problem that re.MULTILINE (re.M for short) was made for.  Compile the pattern as:

```
pattern6 = re.compile(r"Time: .*$", flags=re.M)
```

You can make that more specific by using r"^Time: .*$", requiring "Time: " to start a line, or add some leading space tolerance with r"^\s*Time: .*$".

Maybe this is paranoid, but the first thing I'd do before searching is filter out the \r\n newlines.  I don't have to do this on Windows Python 2.7, but I don't see a guarantee in the docs that all environments will treat \r\n and \n equivalently. The easy way to do that is `re.sub("\r\n", "\n", s)` to replace every "\r\n" in s with a "\n". *[Note: The easier way is to use s.replace(), but as I said in the comments, this works.]*

```
s1 = 'DOMA A\r\nName: Ryan\r\nBest: 1\r\nAlias: 3K\r\nLocation: Eng\r\nGame Wins: 51\r\nTime: 09:10:50'
s2 = 'DOMA A\r\nName: Ryan\r\nBest: 1\r\nAlias: 3K\r\nLocation: Eng\r\nGame Wins: 51\r\nTime: 09:10:50\r\nREF: Yes'

print "s1: ", pattern6.findall( re.sub('\r\n', '\n', s1) )
print "s2: ", pattern6.findall( re.sub('\r\n', '\n', s2) )
```

Output:

```
s1:  ['Time: 09:10:50']
s2:  ['Time: 09:10:50']
```

Another advantage here is that ^ and $ don't capture anything, so you don't end up with the \r\n being part of the match, and you don't need to add parentheses to make that happen.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what the re.sub is actually doing, able to explain that bit too me a little bit?

Comment: It replaces every \r\n with just \n, changing CP/M newlines (used in windows) into Unix newlines (used everywhere else).  (MacOS used just \r newlines prior to OSX, but that's pretty much dead.)

Comment: I guess I should have used the .replace method instead of re.sub(). What can a say...I had a head full of regular expressions and took the first thing I thought of.  That works, anyway, with results pasted from an Idle 2.7 session.

Answer (score 3):

Make the delimiter `\r\n` *or* `$` (which means "end of string" in a regex) - also - instead of multiple patterns, just use one generic pattern, and put it in a dictionary, then extract the named parts after:

```
s = 'DOMA A\r\nName: Ryan\r\nBest: 1\r\nAlias: 3K\r\nLocation: Eng\r\nGame Wins: 51\r\nTime: 09:10:50'
import re
res = dict(re.findall(r'(.*?): (.*?)(?:\r\n|$)', s))
# {'Name': 'Ryan', 'Alias': '3K', 'Location': 'Eng', 'Time': '09:10:50', 'Game Wins': '51', 'Best': '1'}
```

Comment: Hey, by making the delimiter `\r\n` it stops it from working for some reason. I have a real problem maing one generic pattern for my data as I can never work out how to do them correctly.

I love the dict method you're using for this though.

Comment: On my main script yeah, just wish I could write my own advanced regex like that, I've red the regex python docs way too many times